# Dynamically update JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular, rest

I am trying to get JSON data to my angular front end from php backend.Json data's first property
"`stock_price`" changes randomly, but the JSON data's time property should be increment with seconds.
Which means that,

```
{
stock_price: 19,
time: 1
}
```

next it should be

```
 {
stock_price: 26,
time: 2
}
```

like that.

When i try this exact php script with browser/postman , it updates in every page refresh/Post request as 
i expected.

But when i console it in an Angular app, the `time` property doesn't change. `time` is stick to 1.

[image]

What can i do, in order to get an updating json reply.

**php file**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

session_start();

$time = isset($_SESSION['time']) ? $_SESSION['time'] : 0;


$stock_price = rand(10,100);

$arr['stock_price'] = $stock_price;
$arr['time'] = ++$time;

echo json_encode($arr);

$_SESSION['time'] = $time;
?>
```

**Angular app component file**

```
export class AppComponent {


  ngOnInit(){
    this._helper.helperHelp()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

 constructor(private _helper:HelperService){
  setInterval(()=>{
    this.ngOnInit(); },4000); 
  }

 }
```

**service class**

```
export class HelperService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  helperHelp(){
    return this._http.get("http://localhost/restPHP/restphp.php")
               .map(result =>result);
  }


}
```

Comment: send withcredential=true in post/get request

Comment: Move session set __before__ `echo`.

Comment: @u_mulder i didn't get that, session set means, `isset` or `session_start` ?

Comment: It means `$_SESSION['time'] = $time;`

Comment: @u_mulder that didn't worked too , still i get 1 :/

Comment: try also to print $time, before and after update, to check if it get modified or not

Comment: the number is modified in the browser but in angular it throws an error, now HttpErrorResponse  with status code of 200. @Margon

Comment: I'm not that expert with angular, but try to check here: [HttpClient fails to parse an empty 200 response](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18680)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass `time` from Angular. You can send it as `body` if you are using `POST` otherwise in URL (in case of `GET`)

**PHP**

```
$time = isset($_GET['time']) ? $_GET['time'] : 0; // change to $_POST in case of POST
```

**Angular component**

```
export class AppComponent {
    stockData;
    constructor(private _helper:HelperService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getDataFromServer();
        this.scheduleInterval();
    }

    scheduleInterval() {
        setInterval(this.getDataFromServer, 4000);
    }

    getDataFromServer() {
        let time = this.stockData ? this.stockData.time : 0;
        this._helper.helperHelp(time).subscribe(res => { //use time in your service
            this.stockData = res;
            console.log(this.stockData);
        });
    }
}
```

**service**

```
helperHelp(time) { 
    return this._http.get(`http://localhost/restPHP/restphp.php?time=${time}`).map(result =>result); 
}
```

Comment: how can i add `time` in to my service connection function `helperHelp` ? i don't have that much of experience in angular :)

This is it right now 
`helperHelp(){
    return this._http.get("http://localhost/restPHP/restphp.php")
               .map(result =>result);
  }
 `

Comment: use like this this._http.get(`http://localhost/restPHP/restphp.php?time=${time}`)

Comment: i get an error saying `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'helperHelp' of undefined` what will be the reason?

Comment: It shouldn't give. Are you adding `HelperService` in provider?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173131/discussion-between-anshuman-jaiswal-and-avi).

Answer (score 0):

Add the new value in session. currently, you are adding `0` every time. 
Add below code in any PHP file and try to reload every time.

```
session_start();
$time = isset($_SESSION['time']) ? $_SESSION['time'] : 0;
$arr['time'] = ++$time;
$_SESSION["time"] = $time;
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: i tried that, but this works only in browser, not in Angular app